# c# linq-to-sql EF query to match a particular JSON structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, linq

I've JSON with the following structure:

```
[

  {

    "ID": 1,

    "Label": "Reg Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 1,

        "Value": "0x3333cc",

        "Result": 1,

        "Label": null

      },

      {

        "ID": 2,

        "Value": "0x666699",

        "Result": 2,

        "Label": null

      },

      {

        "ID": 3,

        "Value": "0x009966",

        "Result": 3,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },

  {

    "ID": 2,

    "Label": "Spesh Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 11,

        "Value": "0x59699c",

        "Result": 1,

        "Label": null

      },

      {

        "ID": 12,

        "Value": "0x0070ff",

        "Result": 2,

        "Label": null

      },

      {

        "ID": 13,

        "Value": "0x90865e",

        "Result": 3,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },
```

and I have an entity dataset whereby I've joined all the relevant information, and am attempting to produce JSON with that structure via a single linq-to-sql EF query to be returned to the webapi method.

My query so far is:

```
return
    DbContext.Schemes
            .Join(
                DbContext.SchemeColours,
                s => s.SchemeID,
                sc => sc.SchemeID,
                (s, sc) => new
                    {
                        s.SchemeID,
                        s.Label,
                        sc.Colour,
                        sc.Result,
                        sc.ColourID
                    })
            .Select(a =>
                    new Overlay.ReportColourScheme
                        {
                            ID = a.SchemeID,
                            Label = a.Label,
                            Colours = new List<Overlay.ReportColour>
                                {
                                    new Overlay.ReportColour
                                        {
                                            ID = a.ColourID,
                                            Value = a.Colour,
                                            Result = a.Result
                                        }
                                }
                        })
            .ToArray();
```

Which is almost there but not quite:

```
[

  {

    "ID": 1,

    "Label": "Regular Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 1,

        "Value": "0x3333cc",

        "Result": 1,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },

  {

    "ID": 1,

    "Label": "Regular Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 2,

        "Value": "0x666699",

        "Result": 2,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },

  {

    "ID": 1,

    "Label": "Regular Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 3,

        "Value": "0x009966",

        "Result": 3,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },

  {

    "ID": 2,

    "Label": "Protanopia adjusted Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 11,

        "Value": "0x59699c",

        "Result": 1,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },

  {

    "ID": 2,

    "Label": "Protanopia adjusted Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 12,

        "Value": "0x0070ff",

        "Result": 2,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },

  {

    "ID": 2,

    "Label": "Protanopia adjusted Scheme",

    "Colours": [

      {

        "ID": 13,

        "Value": "0x90865e",

        "Result": 3,

        "Label": null

      }

    ]

  },
```

As of course it creates a new list for every resultID. The top-level ID is a SchemeID- what I'm looking for is logic along the lines of: "take the first 3 Results with a particular schemeID, add them to a list in Colours, then move on to the next schemeID"

I believe this will produce identical JSON that I started the post with.

Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you try to group by SchemeID after the first join? That should produce the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are using a `Join` where actually you need a [`Group Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1):

```
return DbContext.Schemes
    .GroupJoin(DbContext.SchemeColours,
        s => s.SchemeID,
        sc => sc.SchemeID,
        (s, colours) => new Overlay.ReportColourScheme
        {
            ID = s.SchemeID,
            Label = s.Label,
            Colours = colours
                .Select(sc => new Overlay.ReportColour
                {
                    ID = sc.ColourID,
                    Value = sc.Colour,
                    Result = sc.Result,
                })
                .ToList()
        })
    .ToArray();
```

But since you are using Entity Framework, it would be much better and eaiser if you define (if you already haven't) and use a **navigation property**:

```
class Scheme
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<SchemeColour> Colours { get; set; }
}
```

and then simply

```
return DbContext.Schemes
    .Select(s => new Overlay.ReportColourScheme
    {
        ID = s.SchemeID,
        Label = s.Label,
        Colours = s.Colours
            .Select(sc => new Overlay.ReportColour
            {
                ID = sc.ColourID,
                Value = sc.Colour,
                Result = sc.Result,
            })
           .ToList()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
return
    DbContext.Schemes
            .Join(
                DbContext.SchemeColours,
                s => s.SchemeID,
                sc => sc.SchemeID,
                (s, sc) => new
                    {
                        s.SchemeID,
                        s.Label,
                        sc.Colour,
                        sc.Result,
                        sc.ColourID
                    })
            // After joining you group by SchemeID, in this way you have 
            // for each SchemeID the group of related items
            .GroupBy(a => a.SchemeID)
            // You then create your result, starting from the main object
            .Select(g =>
                    new Overlay.ReportColourScheme
                        {
                            ID = g.Key,
                            // I suppose you have at least a child for each SchemeID, 
                            // otherwise you can check if the list is empty
                            Label = g.FirstOrDefault().Label,
                            // For each group you create a list of child object
                            Colours = g.Select(v => new Overlay.ReportColour
                                        {
                                            ID = v.ColourID,
                                            Value = v.Colour,
                                            Result = v.Result
                                        }).ToList()
                        })
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: you're probably both correct however the answer marked is a lil' more succinct within the EF

Comment: @notsoobvious no problem bro :)